Upper bound on the total size of the state space of the tracks that can be formed.
I am trying to make sense of the upper bound on the total size of the state space of the tracks that can be formed using the pieces in the below image.
The upper bound given is $$\frac{168^{32}}{12! \cdot 16!\cdot 2! \cdot 2!}.$$
I understand the denominator. That is, we can interchange identical pieces. There are 12 identical straight pieces etc. It is the numerator I am having trouble with.
If we assume for a second that the pieces are all different then we have $$12 + 16 \cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 2 = 52$$
ways to select a piece at each stage. If we factor in the biggest possible track splitting factor of 3 we get 156 possible choices at each of the 32 stages. I get the factors of two from the fact we can rotate track pieces. For instance in the "bend" we can flip it to induce a turn to the left instead of a turn to the right.
From looking at the solutions, there is a missing factor of two in my calculations:
$$12 + 16 \cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 2 + 2 \color{red}{\cdot 2} \cdot 2 = 56$$
What does that factor of 2 represent?


One of the splitters has two extremities fitting (So another doubling factor)

What counts as an acceptable track in the track space? I would guess it has to be connected. Does it also have to be closed? Does it have to use every available piece? I would guess this upper bound comes from allowing track designs that are not physically possible because the track would intersect itself, but without knowing the other rules, it is hard to say where the calculation is coming from.
